# Trying to use an async function with npm http-hash

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am trying to use http-hash module in order to construct an API for my application. I am using AVA as my test runner for my previous test. When I run the "npm test" command, I get this error in my console:

```
import { send } from 'micro'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I am using a linter and it doesn't send me any error. Here is my package.json, where you can see that I am using some babel plugins in order to transpile generators:

```
{
"name": "pos_lisa-api",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "LISA POS REST API",
"scripts": {
  "lint": "standard",
  "test": "npm run lint && ava"
},
"author": "Mauricio Cano Giraldo",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
  "ava": "^0.18.1",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-register": "^6.23.0",
  "standard": "^8.6.0",
  "test-listen": "^1.0.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-runtime": "^6.22.0",
  "http-hash": "^2.0.0",
  "micro": "^7.0.6",
  "request": "^2.79.0",
  "request-promise": "^4.1.1",
  "uuid-base62": "^0.1.0"
},
"standard": {
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ]
}
```

}

And here is my node file, where i get the error:

```
'use strict'

import { send } from 'micro'
import httpHash from 'http-hash'

const hash = httpHash()

hash.set('GET /:id', async function getCliente (req, res, params) {
  send(res, 200, params)
})

export default async function main (req, res) {
  let method = req.method
  let url = req.url

  let match = hash.get(`${method.toUpperCase()} ${url}`)

  if (match.handler) {
    try {
      await match.handler(req, res, match.params)
    } catch (e) {
      send(res, 500, { error: e.message })
    }
  } else {
    send(res, 404, { error: 'La ruta no fue encontrada' })
  }
}
```

I am reading around the web and I don't find anything. Please, help me! I would appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVA only transpiles the test files you want to run, but not the modules you're importing in them. But you can tell AVA to also transpile the imported modules by requiring `babel-register` (https://github.com/avajs/ava#transpiling-imported-modules). And because you configured babel already you can also tell it to use your config. Add this to your `package.json`

```
"ava": {
  "babel": "inherit",
  "require": ["babel-register"]
}
```

If you'd like to use the babel config AVA uses, you can leave off the `"babel": "inherit"`, or you can define an entirely different one if you wish. But usually it's best to just inherit your config.

Answer (score 0):

Using a .babelrc instead may work.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks a lot for your answer. I am learning node, so this kind of concepts are new for me. A .babelrc is a file like package.json? And it have to be at the root directory of the project? In advance, thanks